# Why my ACRA plugin doesn't send any data to mail message body?

Tags: android, acra

I have such ACRA sender class:

```
@ReportsCrashes(formUri = "",
mailTo = "****@gmail.com",
mode = ReportingInteractionMode.TOAST,
customReportContent = [ReportField.ANDROID_VERSION,ReportField.APPLICATION_LOG,ReportField.PHONE_MODEL,ReportField.APP_VERSION_CODE],
resToastText = R.string.crash_toast_text)

class AcraReports : Application() {
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        ACRA.init(this)
    }
}
```

this code opens mail app via intent as I see but it doesn't upload any data to message body. Why does it happen and how to send data? I thought that this variable:

```
customReportContent = ...
```

will send all data into mail app and fill message body, but it doesn't happen :(

Comment: Whichever ACRA version you're using, it's outdated. Use the current version.

Comment: @F43nd1r, I use the last version which I found on GitHub)

Comment: This is Acra 4.x whereas the latest version is 5.5.1

Comment: So you think that it will help me to fill email body with data?

Comment: It is likely. There have been many fixes especially for newer android versions. Follow https://github.com/ACRA/acra/wiki/BasicSetup. You also might want to set reportAsFile (https://www.acra.ch/javadoc/latest/org/acra/annotation/AcraMailSender.html#reportAsFile--) to false if you prefer report content in the body.

Comment: @F43nd1r, I have such problem after updating lib ver - `Failed to resolve: ch.acra:acra:5.1.3`